# Android sqlite delete trigger on conflict

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have a problem with a delete trigger.

The trigger is **before delete on** (or **after delete on**) and the table has a **unique () on conflict replace**. As far as I know, a **replace** will do a **delete** -> **insert** on the table, but it seems, that the trigger isn't fired.

I checked the trigger and while I delete the row manually (with SQLite Editor on Android) the trigger is called. Has I to set my database into something special in my app to call this trigger?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution at [SQLite fire DELETE trigger on a REPLACE](http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2012/06/sqlite-fire-delete-trigger-on-a-replac/)

> Delete triggers fire when rows are removed due to a REPLACE conflict resolution. This feature is only enabled when recursive triggers are enabled.

With the help of

```
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) { // in SQLiteOpenHelper
    super.onOpen(db);

    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA recursive_triggers = true");
    }
}
```

it worked.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.